# Theming menu block module drupal, get rid of default block style

Tags: drupal, drupal-navigation

After lots of trying, i finally managed to find out how to make my [menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489049/bootstrap-navbar-active-class-drupal) active in drupal 7, using the drupal menu block module.

There is one nasty thing which i can't find just a simple solution for, a default block style is still surrounding my menu, and i need to get rid of that.

I tried to override the blocks using:

menu-block-wrapper--[menu name].tpl.php

But it only change things inside the menu block, here an example. I need to get rid of the gray area around the menu:

[image]

Anyone any idea's and suggestions.

Comment: In some cases it's easier to use CSS to get rid of un wanted element, i.e. set it margin/padding/border to 0.